# When are infinite dimensional path algebras hereditary?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

I allready asked this on MO, but did not get any answer.

**Given a finite  quiver with relations. When is the path algebra modulo relations hereditary?**

If the path algebra is finite dimensional or there are no relations, the answer is well known. **What happens if the path algebra is infinite dimensional and there are relations?**

I know that the question is everything but precise, however I would appreciate any reference dealing with this topic.

Comment: Do you assume $I \subseteq J^2$ (where $I$ is the ideal generated by the relations and $J$ is the ideal generated by the arrows)?

Comment: Note that the path algebra with no relations is always hereditary.

Comment: Yes, you can  assume that $I\subset J^2$ if that helps.

Comment: Then I believe $J/I$ is not projective, which contradicts $kQ/I$ being hereditary. (In a hereditary ring, submodules of projectives should be projective.) I have to think a bit to formalize the proof.

Comment: Here is a proof sketch, details need to be checked and filled in. There is an epimorphism of $kQ/I$-modules $J/IJ \rightarrow J/I \rightarrow 0$ with $J/IJ$ projective. If $J/I$ is projective, then this morphism splits and we get (I think) an isomorphism $J/IJ \simeq J/I$, also as $kQ$-modules. This leads to a contradiction since the finite dimensional spaces $J^m(J/IJ)/J^{m+1}(J/IJ)$ and $J^m(J/I)/J^{m+1}(J/I)$ have different dimensions.

Comment: Proving that $J/IJ$ is projective might not be needed, only that it is a $kQ/I$-module.

Comment: To reach a contradiction one could also argue $I/IJ \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra is $A=kQ/I$ with the assumptions $I \subseteq J^2$ and $I/(JI+IJ) \neq 0$, where $J$ is the ideal in $kQ$ generated by the arrows.

Assume $A$ is hereditary. Then $J/I$ is a projective $A$-module and the exact sequence of $A$-modules $$0 \rightarrow I/IJ \rightarrow J/IJ \rightarrow J/I \rightarrow 0$$ must split. Let $s \colon J/IJ \rightarrow I/IJ$ denote a retraction.

Let $x$ be an element in $I \smallsetminus (JI+IJ)$. Since $I \subseteq J^2$, we can write $$x=p_1 q_1 + \cdots + p_n q_n$$  with $p_i,q_i \in J$  for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Then $$x+IJ=s(p_1 q_1 + \cdots + p_n q_n+IJ)=p_1 s(q_1) + \cdots + p_n s(q_n) +IJ \in JI+IJ,$$ a contradiction.

Therefore $A$ is not hereditary.

Comment: I am assuming here the existence of a minimal relation, that is $I/(JI+IJ) \neq 0$. Perhaps this is automatic.